# Is there really a NATO standard cup of coffee?

Tags: coffee-culture

Standards bodies do tend to occupy themselves with making standards for things, but is it just a joke?

What next, ISO standard cup of tea?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such standard, it's a slang.

This made up standard is not only applicable to coffee, but apparently used also for tea.

As far as I can confirm, this standard is a counter act against NATO's will to standardize everything in between European and American armies. Tea, is quite interesting as British army likes to consume it with milk where others prefer lemon.

Therefore, beverage (either tea or coffee) + milk + two sugar is known as NATO standard as an army slang.

Probably rooted from this, ISO 0 is another slang for beverage with milk, no sugar. And ISO 2 is the exact NATO standard.

For more info please see [here](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/I/ISO-standard-cup-of-tea.html).

Answer (score 1):

ISO standard 3103: 'Method for preparation of a liquor of tea for use in sensory tests.'

see also: 
British Standard BS6008: 'How to make a standard cup of tea.'